# How can I use beautifulsoup in python to replace multiple words (terms) including html tags?

Tags: python, html, replace, beautifulsoup

I try to find and replace terms (with links) in html file, but I like to maintain the other html structure.
First, I tried to find tags with `string`, but because of child tags the string don't include all text, and replacing
it with modified string removes all child tags. Then I tried to use `get_text()` method, but for replacing, it has the
same problem. Finally, I got the contents of every paragraph with `__str__()` method to get all the html content, and
replace it with new BeautifulSoup object (to include all tags within):

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def Exclude_paragraph(cls_name):
    return cls_name is None or cls_name not in ("excluded1", "excluded2")

def Replace_by_ref(m, term):
    return "<a href='#" + term["anchor"] + "'>" + m.group(0) + "</a>"

terms = [{"line": "special configurable device", "anchor": "#term_1"},
         {"line": "analytical performance", "anchor": "term_2"},
         {"line": "instructions for use", "anchor": "term_4"},
         {"line": "calibrator", "anchor": "term_3"},
         {"line": "label", "anchor": "term_6"},
         {"line": "kit", "anchor": "term_5"}]
# There are almost 100 terms searched in thousands of lines
with open(os.path.join("HTML", "test2.html"), "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    html = file.read()
html_bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for term in terms:
    regex = r"\b" + term["line"] + r"s?\b"
    regex = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    body_txts = html_bs.body.find_all("p", class_=Exclude_paragraph)
    for paragraph in body_txts:
        body_tag_html = paragraph.__str__()
        new_tag = regex.sub(lambda m: Replace_by_ref(m, term), body_tag_html)
        if new_tag != body_tag_html:
            print("\nFound:", term["line"])
            print("String:", paragraph.string)
            print("Get_text():", paragraph.get_text())
            print("Replacement:", new_tag)
            paragraph.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(new_tag, "html.parser"))
```

In the end the modified html file is saved (not included here). But what about when some terms include html tags, like

```
<i>special</i> configurable device
```

(or something else)? First of all, my regex don't find this at all, not to speak of how to replace it. Any ideas?

Edit: added short example HTML code:

```
<html><head></head>
<body><h1>Test document</h1>
<p><i>special</i> configurable device, analytical performance, calibrator, instructions for use, kit, label.</p>
<p class='excluded1'>No terms here.</p>
<h2>Glossary</h2>
<dl>
<dt id="term_2">analytical performance</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_3">calibrator</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_4">instructions for use</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_5">kit</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_6">label</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_1">special configurable device</dt><dd>...</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

The original html code is much longer, including thousands of terms within text. I already made IDs to the glossary, now I try to make cross references to them.

Comment: Could you give an example of the sort of HTML code you have, and what sort if HTML you'd want to change it to?  For example, are you just trying to replace certain `href` values for certain links?

Comment: Example of HTML code given.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need.  Loop through your `terms` list, then look for a  tag in the HTML whose `id=` matches `terms["anchor"]`.  Then replace it with the link you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html><head></head>
<body><h1>Test document</h1>
<p><i>special</i> configurable device, analytical performance, calibrator, instructions for use, kit, label.</p>
<p class='excluded1'>No terms here.</p>
<h2>Glossary</h2>
<dl>
<dt id="term_2">analytical performance</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_3">calibrator</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_4">instructions for use</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_5">kit</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_6">label</dt><dd>...</dd>
<dt id="term_1">special configurable device</dt><dd>...</dd>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

terms = [{"line": "special configurable device", "anchor": "term_1"},
         {"line": "analytical performance", "anchor": "term_2"},
         {"line": "instructions for use", "anchor": "term_4"},
         {"line": "calibrator", "anchor": "term_3"},
         {"line": "label", "anchor": "term_6"},
         {"line": "kit", "anchor": "term_5"}]

for t in terms:

    # Identify the <dt> tag you want to replace.
    anchor = t["anchor"]
    original_tag = soup.find("dt", id=anchor)

    # Get rid of the <dd> tag that follows it.
    original_tag.find_next("dd").decompose()

    # Generate the new tag as a BS object
    new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href=anchor)
    new_tag.string = t["line"]

    # Do the replacement
    original_tag.replaceWith(new_tag)

print(soup)
```

The output is:

```
<html><head></head>
<body><h1>Test document</h1>
<p><i>special</i> configurable device, analytical performance, calibrator, instructions for use, kit, label.</p>
<p class="excluded1">No terms here.</p>
<h2>Glossary</h2>
<dl>
<a href="term_2">analytical performance</a>
<a href="term_3">calibrator</a>
<a href="term_4">instructions for use</a>
<a href="term_5">kit</a>
<a href="term_6">label</a>
<a href="term_1">special configurable device</a>
</dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I already made IDs to glossary, now want to make internal links (crross references) to the glossary, not from it. Like this:
`<p><a href="#term_1"><i>special</i> configurable device</a>, <a href="#term_2">analytical performance</a>...`

Comment: The problem is the first link: how to find it, and how to include html tag `<i>` (from the original document) in it?

Comment: If it's just an extra hashtag that goes at the front of the `href` value, then just change the first `new_tag` line to `new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href="#" + anchor)`.

Comment: This still doesn't solve my problem. Please look closely my original program and run it. You can see that the python code doesn't find terms that has tags in it, like `<p><i>special</i> configurable device, ...`. This should be changed to `<p><a href='#term_1'><i>special</i> configurable device</a>, ...`. The other terms are found and replaced nicely.

Comment: Then you need to go back and edit your original post to make it clear what, exactly, your problem is and what you're expecting.